# Is there a way to not delete the user input in a text file after running it again?

Tags: python, file

Whenever I run this program it will ask for a username and a password, store them as the first values in the two lists, open up a text file, and then write `password:` and `username:` then whatever `username_Database[0]` and `password_Database[0]` are. The problem is when I run the program again, it deletes the previous values. Is there anyway to save the user input and not have it deleted when I run the program again?

```
import time

username_Database = []
password_Database = []

username = input("Enter a username\n")
username_Database.append(username)

password = input("Enter a password\n")
password_Database.append(password)

print('You are now registered and your user name is \n' + username_Database[0] + "\n and your password is \n" + password_Database[0] + "\n")
print("Saving...")

filename = open("data.txt", "w")
filename.add("Password: " + str(password_Database[0] + "\n"))
filename.add("Username: " + str(username_Database[0] + "\n"))


time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `write` mode when opening the file, it will overwrite everything inside the file. Change it to `append` mode.

```py
# Using append mode
filename = open("data.txt", "a")

# It should be write instead of add
filename.write ("Password: " + str(password_Database[0] + "\n"))
filename.write ("Username: " + str(username_Database[0] + "\n"))
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it. Also the filename.add was a mistake I already fixed.